# What is wrong with this button? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, button, time, setinterval

I am making a nice little button game. It'll probably get dark at the end. I just started earlier, and I'm at a problem. I'll display [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/Mazedotexe/m463r5g8/) below and then explain my problem.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="change()" id="btn" class="c">hello?</button>
<div class="c">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/mgtbkZ4x/table-removebg-preview.png" id="table" class="obj" onclick = "hide(t)">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/SRRy9m9z/image-removebg-preview-2.png" id="rock" class="obj" onclick = "hide(r)">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  outline: groove 3px;
  outline-color: #00e4e5;
  background-color: #4040ff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.c {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  background-color: #1C1412;
}
.obj {
  height: auto;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #1C1412;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#rock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And finally, javascript:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true
})
```

Okay. Now that that's over with, I'll explain my problem. Feel free to test out my code on the jsfiddle website (you don't have to sign up, in case you're wondering.)
When 'times' is 33, and the button says "alright. i'm closing my eyes. I'll open them in 10", it's supposed to count down, but it won't. Inside the switch, I have a setInterval set up (and a clearInterval) that seems like it's set up perfectly, but it doesn't work.
It's supposed to count down from 10, and then say "hey! you didn't hide!" (the empty space after is just filler I will remove after it's fixed.) Please help me with this problem.

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76926279/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem that is preventing the countdown from working as you expected lies in the way you're **clearing** the interval at this part of your code.

```
case (33):
  var count = 10
  var dt = setInterval(function() {
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(dt);
      change();
    } else {
      count--;
      btn.innerText = "my eyes are now closed, and i'll open them in " + count;
    }
  }, 1000);
  clearInterval(dt); // This line is not needed and is clearing the interval immediately
  break;
```

You're clearing the interval right after you set it up, which is causing the countdown not to work.

Remove the `clearInterval(dt);` line after setting the interval.

```
case (33):
  var count = 10;
  var dt = setInterval(function() {
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(dt);
      change();
    } else {
      count--;
      btn.innerText = "my eyes are now closed, and i'll open them in " + count;
    }
  }, 1000);
  break; // Removed the clearInterval(dt);
```